# JsonNode isTextual() inexplicably returns false

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have a Jetty WebSocket server in Java that accepts incoming messages in JSON format and performs trivial parsing. This is done by using the [Jackson databind library](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind) to convert the incoming message to a `JsonNode` object. I am trying to validate some of the data fields but I am having a baffling issue with `isTextual()`. I have boiled this down to the most minimal test but still cannot figure it out.

This is essentially what I've got:

```
// sample JSON: {...,"key":"de305d54","topic":"de305d54"}
// action is another JsonNode that contains the "topic" and "key" fields
final JsonNode actionKey = validateKey(action.get("key"));
final JsonNode actionTopic = validateTopic(action.get("topic"));

// both validation functions perform the same check
private JsonNode validateKey(JsonNode key) throws Exception {
    if (!key.isTextual())
        throw new Exception("invalid key");
    return key;
}
private JsonNode validateTopic(JsonNode topic) throws Exception {
    if (!topic.isTextual())
        throw new Exception("invalid topic");
    return topic;
}
```

The problem is that this **always** throws `java.lang.Exception: invalid topic`.

And for the hell of it, here is the result of printing the JSON values:

```
System.out.println("topic is: " + action.get("topic"));
System.out.println("key is: " + action.get("key"));

// topic is: "de305d54"
// key is: "de305d54"
```

And one more bizarre piece of evidence: according to [the JsonNode docs](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.2.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonNode.html) the `textValue()` call will **NOT** do any type conversion, if the value is not a `String` it will return `null`. But the results of `textValue()` prints a string.

```
System.out.println(action.get("topic").textValue());
// de305d54
```

Comment: This works fine for me and doesn't throw any exceptions. Post a complete, compilable, piece of code that reproduces this.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis thanks for the reply. That may be tough because there is lot of interwoven code. I guess the issue must be hidden somewhere in there. I'll see if I can add a complete example that reproduces it.

Answer (score 2):

From the jackson docs:

> public boolean isBinary(): Method that can be used to check if this
>   node represents binary data (Base64 encoded). Although this will be
>   externally written as Json String value, isTextual() will return false
>   if this method returns true.

Your data does *look* like Base64 encoded. I suspect this may be why isTextual() is returning false.